# Display images from different folders

Tags: php, image

using external web pages customers can create a ticket with different values and upload images. All these values are passed to an internal system that allows people to manage the tickets but are shown only the database values and not the images on a simple php page. When a ticket is created the ticket and the images folder (that is automatically created) share a common and unique ID. So the ticket is the same as the folder name.Searching for the ID the pages with all the data is shown using this:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
 

if($link === false){
    die("ERRORE: DB error. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
$num = $_GET['ticket_id']; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ticket_id = '$num'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

?>
            
<form action="edit.php" method="post">

<table id="myTable">
```

etc

I tried using something like glob function but I always get "no images to display"

```
  <?php $thumbs = glob("2021/ticket_att/$num/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE)?>

    <?php
    if(count($thumbs)) {
      natcasesort($thumbs);
      foreach($thumbs as $thumb) {
      ?>
          <li>
              <img src="<?php echo $thumb ?>" width="50%" alt="ticket image" />
          </li> 

    <?php
        }} else {
          echo "No images to display!";
        }
    ?>
```

Where am I getting wrong?

Thank you!

--> UPDATE <--

The glob function works if I change the value of $num into a fixed value (for example

```
<?php $thumbs = glob("2021/ticket_att/123456/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE)?>
```

but if I check the value of $num is correct. Maybe the functions doesnt' read a variable value?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to consider physical vs. virtual folder names when using `glob()`?

Comment: I think you should go with [readdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) instead of this.

Comment: It would probably be easier to update a database table to contain the image names when you upload them, rather than searching for them each time.

Comment: Thank you all! The folders I try to reach have an exact copy of the one virtual one. I can try with reddir, of course. @droopsnoot I'm sure it would be easier but the images are uploaded by a third service software and I only get an exact copy of this. All the files have different names as every customer uploads it after taking it with smartphone or camera or idk...

Comment: In the doc for `glob` it does say "No tilde expansion or parameter substitution is done.", so I wonder whether that confirms that it doesn't comply with the normal PHP rules when the string is enclosed in double-quotes. However, you can try that in a few seconds by concatenating the value manually.